# Passing static Method to a button factory (Java)

Tags: java, button, plugins, swt

I am coding a little Plugin for Eclipse (using SWT), which creates a view with a couple of buttons. In order not to produce redundant code I want to create some kind of factory method to create my buttons for me. The call would be something like:

```
Button button0 = createButton(new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH), "Test DB zurücksetzen", btnHight, btnWidth, new FormAttachment(0, 2), new FormAttachment(0,2));
```

My factory, so far, looks like this:

```
private Button createButton(Button buttonToCreate, String buttonText, int height, int width, FormAttachment left, FormAttachment top) {

    buttonToCreate.setText(buttonText);
    FormData formData = new FormData();
    formData.height = height;
    formData.width = width;
    formData.left = left;
    formData.top = top;
    buttonToCreate.setLayoutData(formData);

    buttonToCreate.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            Actions.editPropertys(); 
        }
    });

    return buttonToCreate;

}
```

My Question is: How can I pass the Method of the Actions class I want to execute to the factory as a parameter?

Comment: There is no need to pass a static method into the factory method because you can call a static method simply using the class name.

Comment: @amitpandey  I think that the OP wants to pass the static method to be able to invoke a distinct method according to the call to `createButton()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convey it as a `Runnable` parameter of the method.

For example :

```
private Button createButton(Button buttonToCreate, String buttonText, int height, int width, FormAttachment left, FormAttachment top, Runnable actionOnSelection) {

  // ...
    buttonToCreate.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            actionOnSelection.run(); // change here
        }
    });
}
```

and invoke it :

```
Button button0 = createButton(new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH), "Test DB zurücksetzen", btnHight, btnWidth, new FormAttachment(0, 2), new FormAttachment(0,2), 
                Actions::editPropertys); // other change here
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!